# OrientDB Query Across Multiple Databases

Tags: database, orientdb

Is it possible to issue an OrientDB SQL that joins or searches across OrientDB Databases? For example, in mysql, we can prefix with the schemaName.TableName.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, do you wanna query across multiple databeses in SQL? Thx. Regards

Comment: Orientdb does not support this kind of queries at the moment.